# How do I use the Facebook PHP SDK to read multiple user feeds at the same time?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

Note: I already know how to do this with one user only, but what I want to do is access multiple account feeds simultaneously.

I had a few ideas but encountered problems:

Idea : *Have them all logged in at the same time.*

**Problem :** 
I need to do it in one computer. There's no discussion specifically in the FB docs. I don't know of any way to log out and log them back in one by one. (It's probably not a good idea anyway)

Idea : *Access their feed even when they're offline using the permissions I'm granted.*

**Problem :**
Don't know how, and didn't find any previously asked questions here.

Any guidance or help in solving this is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can achieve this by using Facebook Stream Api but unfortunately it is not publicly available. You will need to apply for that.

Comment: @Haridarshan: You can not apply for that, and it sounds rather like the wrong thing to begin with.

Comment: Have them log in, extend their access token (valid for up to 60 days), and store it somewhere.